# spark dataframes did not divide correctly after joining

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join

I have 3 spark dataframes, would like to join them on column BAQ and create 2 new columns from division (`dtfAvgEnd("avg(AAG)")/dtfAvgWeek("avg(AAG)"`) and `dtfAvgLong("avg(AAG)")/dtfAvgWeek("avg(AAG)")`).

```
scala> dtfAvgWeek.filter("BAQ='3310101041401034198668'").show(10,false)
+----------------------+-----------------+                                      ]
|BAQ                   |avg(AAG)         |
+----------------------+-----------------+
|3310101041401034198668|147.6660606060606|
+----------------------+-----------------+

scala> dtfAvgEnd.filter("BAQ='3310101041401034198668'").show(10,false)
+----------------------+------------------+                                     ]
|BAQ                   |avg(AAG)          |
+----------------------+------------------+
|3310101041401034198668|58.360833333333325|
+----------------------+------------------+

scala> dtfAvgLong.filter("BAQ='3310101041401034198668'").show(10,false)
+----------------------+------------------+                                     1]
|BAQ                   |avg(AAG)          |
+----------------------+------------------+
|3310101041401034198668|121.46857142857144|
+----------------------+------------------+

scala> val dtfRatiConsSing=dtfAvgWeek.
     |   filter("BAQ='3310101041401034198668'").
     |   join(dtfAvgEnd,Seq("BAQ"),"inner").
     |   join(dtfAvgLong,Seq("BAQ"),"inner").
     |   withColumn("Rati_End",dtfAvgEnd("avg(AAG)")/dtfAvgWeek("avg(AAG)")).
     |   withColumn("Rati_long",dtfAvgLong("avg(AAG)")/dtfAvgWeek("avg(AAG)"));
dtfRatiConsSing: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [BAQ: string, avg(AAG): double ... 4 more fields]
```

And I got this. So Rati_Long worked out but Rati_End not. And I dont understand what went wrong.

```
scala>   dtfRatiConsSing.
     |   show(20,false);
+----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------+------------------+
|BAQ                   |avg(AAG)          |avg(AAG)          |avg(AAG)          |Rati_End|Rati_long         |
+----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------+------------------+
|3310101041401034198668|147.66606060606063|58.360833333333346|121.46857142857142|1.0     |0.8225896386077629|
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with your provided data. Maybe a typo in your code somewhere?

Comment: As a better practice, consider renaming your columns so that there are no duplicate column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> dtfRatiCons.filter("BAQ='3310101041401034198668'").show(10,false);
+----------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|BAQ                   |AVGWeek           |AVGEnd           |AVGLong           |Rati_End          |Rati_long         |
+----------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|3310101041401034198668|147.66606060606063|58.36083333333334|121.46857142857142|0.3952217123813354|0.8225896386077629|
+----------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I renamed the AVG columns and it worked.